# How to pass argument in Android Navigation using Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created my NavGraph using the Kotlin DSL and everything is fine. But I'm struggling to pass a simple argument between destinations.

I'm folowing this Android Docs without success: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-kotlin-dsl#constants

Part of graph that adds the argument as the docs says:

```
            fragment<RestaurantsTabsFragment>(
                "${CampusSelectorDestinations.restaurantsTabsFragment}/" +
                        CampusSelectorArguments.campusId
            ) {
                argument(CampusSelectorArguments.campusId) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    defaultValue = "test"
                }
            }
```

Code with the navigation action trying to pass a argument:

```
        campusesAdapter.onCampusClick = { campusId ->
                 findNavController().navigate("${CampusSelectorDestinations.restaurantsTabsFragment}/" + campusId
        }
```

Error I get:

> IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/restaurantsTabsFragment/jCkuLbzRHtW0CUzDFWYw } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph

Can anyone help me? I can provide more information if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern to pass the argumet route is wrong at the docs:

[image]

For luck, I've found this explanation inside a Navigation Lib class and that solved my problem (after 2 days struggling):

> ...
> In addition to a direct Uri match, the following features are supported:
> Uris without a scheme are assumed as http and https. For example, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) will match http://www.example.com and https://www.example.com. Placeholders in the form of {placeholder_name} matches 1 or more characters. The String value of the placeholder will be available in the arguments Bundle with a key of the same name. For example, [http://www.example.com/users/{id}](http://www.example.com/users/%7Bid%7D) will match http://www.example.com/users/4. The .* wildcard can be used to match 0 or more characters.
> These Uris can be declared in your navigation XML files by adding one or more  elements as a child to your destination.
> ...

Hope someone from Google see this and fixes the docs. (or explain if I'm wrong)

Comment: You should [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828&template=1093757) to correct the documentation.

Comment: done Ian, thank you

Comment: For required args you do path/{name-of-argument}, for optional you do path?name={name-of-argument}. In the second case the "name" query paramenter can be anything, you just have to match it when navigating to this route. There is no option to have a route such as "user/{id}"  and have the "id" being optional so it can match with both "/user" and "/suer/435". https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation

Answer (score 1):

Just put your arguments into curved breaks and separate them by slash as it shown in the example below.

1. Define your destination with all required argument:

   ```
   fragment<TransactionFragment>("${MainNavRoute.transaction}/{arg1}/{arg2}") {
      argument("arg1") {
          type = NavType.StringType
      }
      argument("arg2") {
          type = NavType.LongType
      }
   ```
2. Navigation to the destination:

   findNavController().navigate("${MainNavRoute.transaction}/string_value/2")

Also, I have reported an issue to the tracker too. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221895357